# create my own global variable in nuxt.js (with vuetify)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm developing an app with nuxt and I'm tired of having to write an if statement in pages using  this.$Vuetify.breakpoint.name == 'xs'  for responsiveness every time. So I would like to create my own variable and call this long variable.here is my code↓

(mynuxtapp/plugins/createCustomVar.js)

```js
  import Vue from "vue";

  Vue.prototype.$bp = Vue.prototype.$vuetify.breakpoint.name;
  console.log(Vue.prototype.$bp);
```

I have already set nuxtconfig to run the plugin.
But it returns an error:
TypeError: Cannot read property'breakpoint' of undefined.
Apparently I can't access vuetify using "$", even though I can do it in pages.

What should I do? and Are there any easier ways or best practices?
Thank you for reading the question at the end!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$vuetify` property exists on the Nuxt context, not the Vue prototype.

Each module under `plugins/` should return a function that receives the Nuxt context as the first argument. That context contains the `$vuetify` object setup by the `@nuxtjs/vuetify` plugin.

The second argument of the Plugin API is `inject`, which allows you to [inject globals into the Nuxt context](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context).

So your plugin should look similar to this:

```js
// ~/plugins/myGlobals.js
export default ({ $vuetify }, inject) => {
  // inject makes `$bp` available in context (the `$` prefix is automatically prefixed)
  inject('bp', $vuetify.breakpoint.name)
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-inject-globals-from-plugins?file=plugins%2FmyGlobals.js)

Comment: It's not reactive though. In your demo the value is always 'xs', the starting value. It never updates regardless of the viewport size.

Answer (score 1):

How about to start with you simply log out the context object and see what you have. I think you'll probably find that the Vuetify object is lying somewhere else.

```
export default (context, inject) => {
  console.log('context:', context)
}
```

Docs for setting plugins can be found [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins#inject-in-root--context)